# Azure DevOps Boards and Dashboards

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

**Azure Boards Backlog Column Options**

I have multiple teams and as the Admin I would like to set the layout ( column options) for each team for backlogs under (  epics , Feathers and user story) is this possible and how? current each user from each team needs to set the columns as per my setting

**Azure Boards Dashboards**

I been ask to display Tasks , bugs and User story in a table or graph format to display State via sum of Effort ( Example below )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yapc9.png)

when I used "Chart for Work Items" and select Pivot Table I cant select multiple  Columns . Is there way I can do this ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/911nZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

> I have multiple teams and as the Admin I would like to set the layout ( column options) for each team for backlogs under ( epics , Feathers and user story) is this possible and how?

According to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/set-column-options?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#about-persistence-of-column-options), you can't set column options for other members in your team.

> when I used "Chart for Work Items" and select Pivot Table I cant select multiple Columns . Is there way I can do this ?

In the pivot chart configuration, you can only choose one column to show in the table.

If you want to make "Original Estimate","Remaining" and "Completed" showed together, you may need to [create a new field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops) for the work items and add "Original Estimate","Remaining" and "Completed" as the value of the field.

For example:
[image]

Then you can add it in the column option of your query and pick it in the pivot chart as the column.
[image]

Here's the pivot table you can get:

[image]